# Firebase & Google ads

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, firebase-analytics

For example, I've imported 2 event from Google analytics 4 firebase to Google ads account. The events are first open and sessions.

I clearly understand what first open means.

Now, the sessions shows about 2.4k & first open shows 2.2k. can someone please let know what's the reason the sessions is higher than first open

Answer (score 1):

You will always have sessions that are equal to or greater than first opens.
A first open is a session in itself. It's the first session. If the user opens again, it increments the sessions but not the first opens.

Comment: Thank you for that can you also help me understand one more thing please. I believe that the data reported in Google ads are the ones that happen after a Google ad click(when a user's performs a specified event on the app). In this case, can you help me understand how can session start event show more in numbers when compared to first open events in Google ads account. Thank you...

Comment: Hi Thematic.
A session is an instance where a user uses your app or site. A user can use your app or visit your site more than once. 

You can go to the cinema to see a movie every weekend. But you only visited the cinema for your first movie once.